# How to get the tooltip for the element with no children in d3.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

In  D3.js layout , the tooltip is visible only for the nodes which has children .

Find my code attached
https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-thunder-l024x

I have an object some of them contains children , some are not . While displaying them in the chart , the tooltip only visible to the object which has children in it .

```
const dataObj = {
  name: "Home",
  children: [
    {
      name: "A",
      metricsValue: "ma",
      children: [
        {
          name: "A-B",
          value: 1.2,
          metricsValue: "ma-mb"
        },
        {
          name: "A-B-C",
          metricsValue: "ma-mb-mc",
          children: [
            {
              name: "A-B-C-D-1",
              value: 2.5,
              metricsValue: "ma-mb-mc-md-1"
            },
            {
              name: "A-B-C-D-2",
              value: 2.566,
              metricsValue: "ma-mb-mc-md-2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "BCD",
      value: "6.5",
      metricsValue: "m1"
    }
  ]
};
```